# Can I buy manyunity through iTunes for manyland?

Tags: manyland

Is there a way to use money on my iTunes account to buy manyunity on manyland, or steam.

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't buy Minfinity through the iPad/ iPhone app, but if you buy it on the web app (at manyland.com) and then login with the same Google/ Facebook/ Amazon account on iOS, it should have Minfinity and work.